# Syntax error in PHP/SQL file

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a PHP/SQL code which produces a survey for defence companies. Unfortunately, when I answer the questions and click on submit, I get an error saying:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '', '', '', '')' at line 56

Now, the code that I have given you below is only a part of a longer code, and **line 56 corresponds to the very last line**, ie. where it says `VALUES`. (There are other codes that follow line 56, eg closing mysqli connection, but that has nothing to do with my problem). I don't understand why I'm getting this message.

Are you not supposed to use an integer (eg "question1") -- is the digit "1" causing this difficulty? I have trimmed my code -- I have A LOT of numbers, going up to question65, and that is why I cannot delete all the numbers and replace them with strings and then check if it works. That is why I am asking you experts.

Why do I keep getting this syntax error?

```
        $sql = "UPDATE Raptor
      Set `Role` = '$question1',
          `Origin` = '$country',
          `FirstFlight` = '$year',
          `PrimaryUser` = '$question4'
   where  `SessionID` = '$sessionID'";


    $sql="INSERT INTO Raptor (SessionID, Role, Origin, FirstFlight, PrimaryUser)
    VALUES     ('$sessionID', '$question1', '$country', '$year', '$question4')";
```

Comment: MySQL will NEVER see your php variable names. by the time the query string is built and sent to mysql by PHP, the variable names ahve been replaced with their values. You've got an SQL syntax error, but as written above, there's nothing wrong with either of your queries.  Which means you've got something goofy in the PHP code.

Comment: What does `echo $sql;` show you for each query?

Comment: This isn't enough code or information to go on. Far as I'm concerned, this code checks out. What are the values going in?

Comment: The error is claiming that all the variables are null (or empty strings). Your assumption that the 1 in $question1 is causing a problem is unfounded. The error is saying that the query you sent to MySQL ends with '','','','','') and that the syntax error is right about where the first empty string begins.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to answer @Rocket Hazmat's question, but I am not allowed to, so I am answering my own question and am hoping that @Rocket sees it. When I `echo $sql`, I get:

```
VALUES ('***.***.***.** 2014-11-13 18:58:49', 'question1', 'country', 'year', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '1', '1', '', '', '5', '5', '5', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '', '', '', '','', '', '', '')
```

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '', '', '', '', '')' at line 56

What seems to be happening is that the answers that I have answered are appearing on the database, e.g. `1` and `5`, etc, but because I have not answered **all** the questions in the survey, an error is generated. I will see what happens when I answer all the questions. Thanks for pointing out the `echo $sql` - I didn't think of that.

Comment: To answer [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26916254/syntax-error-in-php-sql-file#comment42381169_26916254) from the comments, you can add a comment or you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26916254/edit) your question to add in the additional info.  Please **do not** post this as an answer.  It does not *answer* the question, so it does not belong here.